# Dynamic variables and promises

Tags: multithreading, raku

It seems that dynamic variables don't always survive subroutine calls in threads:

```
sub foo($x, &y = &infix:<+>) {
  my &*z = &y;
  bar($x);
}

sub bar ($x) {
    say &*z($x,$x);

    my $promise = start { bar($x-1) if $x > 0 }
    await $promise;

    # bar($x-1) if $x > 0    # <-- provides the expected result: 6, 4, 2, 0
}
foo(3); # 6, 4, Dynamic variable &*z not found
```

Using a more globally scoped variable also works, so it's not that all variables are lost — it seems specific to dynamics:

```
our &b;

sub foo($a, &c = &infix:<+>) {
  &b = &c;
  bar($a);
}

sub bar ($a) {
    say &b($a,$a);
    my $promise = start { bar($a-1) if $a > 0 }
    await $promise;
}

foo(3); # 6, 4, 2, 0
```

Once the variable is set in `foo()`, it is read without problem in `bar()`.  But when `bar()` is called from inside the promise, the value for `&*z` disappears not on the first layer of recursion but the second.

I'm sensing a bug but maybe I'm doing something weird with the between the recursion/dynamic variables/threading that's messing things up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under current semantics, `start` will capture the context it was invoked in. If dynamic variable lookup fails on the stack of the thread that the `start` executes on (one of those from the thread pool), then it will fall back to looking at the dynamic scope captured when the `start` block was scheduled.

When a `start` block is created during the execution of another `start` block, the same thing happens. However, there is no relationship between the two, meaning that the context captured by the "outer" `start` block will not be searched also. While one could argue for that to happen, it seems potentially problematic to do so. Consider this example:

```
sub tick($n = 1 --> Nil) {
    start {
        await Promise.in(1);
        say $n;
        tick($n + 1);
    }
}
tick();
sleep;
```

This is a (not entirely idiomatic) way to produce a tick every second. Were the inner `start` to retain a reference back to the state of the outer one, for the purpose of dynamic variable lookup, then this program would build up a chain of ever increasing length in memory, which seems like an undesirable behavior.

Comment: Great answer.  This does make sense as to why it would happen.  I'm not sure *where* it should go (either in variables or async stuff) but someone (e.g. me, whenever I finally get free time to dive full on into writing/editing docs) should mention that somewhere.  Thankfully for what I'm doing I can work around it fairly simply and it'll all stay in module-code-land where no one has to see it ha